# FileNotFoundException on IIS7 with ASP.NET Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, iis-7, dynamics-crm-2011

I realy used google and stackoverflow a lot the last few hours but I didnt find a solution or topic which helped me to solve my problem.

The Task and Problem:

I created an ASP.NET Webform which runs perfectly on my local maschine. It allows user to create a customer in Dynamics CRM 2011. Next to that a user can add an Annotation to a customer and add a file to upload.

The next step is to publish this Webform on IIS7, so you can access it remotely, which is on a remote Windows 2008 R2 Server. If I test the Webform now and choose a data from the FileUpload control, IIS7 doesnt get the correct Path `(FileNotFoundException)`, it always uses his root directory and not the Filepath from the data, even if I want to "upload" a file directly from the Server where IIS is installed on.

Stacktrace:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Die Datei "c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\test.txt" konnte nicht gefunden werden.]
System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +12898679
System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath) +2481
System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +229
System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) +102
System.IO.File.OpenRead(String path) +55
FirstWebform._Default.create_Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\flah\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FirstWebform\FirstWebform\Main.aspx.cs:86
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +154
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3707
```

What I have tried:

- I have read that I have to save the file on IIS7 on a temp directory with `FileUpload.Saveas("C:\\folder\\" + FileUpload.Filename)` before I can use it
  but the same problem occurs, the filepath is wrong and it doesnt event get it.
- I tried to get the Pathname by `Path.GetFullPath(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName);` which didnt work either - same with `Server.MapPath();`
- I have set up the rights for the user on the Server

I dont understand why IIS always uses his root directory for the `FileUpload` and why it justs works fine on my local machine.

The important code without my tries:

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    byte[] byteData = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
    stream.Close();

    //Dynamics CRM 2011 upload
    string encodedData = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteData);                     
    newAnnotation.DocumentBody = encodedData;
    EntityReference refNote = new EntityReference();
    refNote.LogicalName = "account";
    refNote.Id = newAccountId;
    newAnnotation.Attributes.Add("objectid", refNote);
    service.Create(newAnnotation);
} else {
    EntityReference refNote = new EntityReference();
    refNote.LogicalName = "account";
    refNote.Id = newAccountId;
    newAnnotation.Attributes.Add("objectid", refNote);
    service.Create(newAnnotation);
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this. Maybe its just a little configuration or my understatement of the whole architecture must be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to handle the file before it can be used.  IIS has received the file, and held it in a temporary location until user code for `FileUpload1` handles the saving.

I believe you have tried the code below already, but just to make sure; as you need to save the file before accessing it.  This is the standard way of doing it, but your code sample does not attempt to save.

Try the following:

```
String savePath = @"c:\temp\uploads\"; // Save folder - Ensure exists, permissions etc

if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    // Append the name of the file to upload to the path.
    savePath += FileUpload1.FileName;

    // TODO : Error checking - verify file is accepted type/size/does not already exist
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);

    int fileLen = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
    Byte[] Input = new Byte[fileLen];
    System.IO.Stream myStream = FileUpload1.FileContent;
    myStream.Read(Input, 0, fileLen);

    // TODO : Other Processing

} else {
    // TODO : Handle not hasfile
}
```

See some examples at the bottom of the page for [FileUpload on MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ysf0192b.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much. Both answers helped me to solve the problem. The first step was to  declare the SavePath before handling the object, and the second one was the "var stream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;" line - together it just managed my problem :).

Thanks for your explanation as well, it opened my mind!
Problem resolved.

Comment: @Flo `FileUpload1.FileContent` should also give you the underlying stream.  But glad to see it working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [FileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream.aspx) to get the actual uploaded contents. For example,

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    var stream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
    byte[] byteData = new byte[FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength];
    stream.Read(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
    stream.Close();

    ...
```

**EDIT**: Regarding the exception that you are getting with your existing code, the problem is with the line `File.OpenRead(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);` - you are trying to open a file with a name on the sever machine while file exists on the client machine. Because you have not mentioned any path information, it is looking for file in some default (say system32) directory - so if client machine and server machine are same and the file is uploaded from root directory then the code would work but for all practical purposes it is useless.